# Why is the function sequence $\{\frac{nx}{2 + n + x}\}^\infty_1$ converges uniformly to $x$ in the interval $0 \le x \le1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

Given function sequence $\{f_n(x)\}^\infty$ defined as $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{2 + n + x}. (0 \le x \le 1)$

I need to find the limit function and whether it converges uniformly or not uniformly.

I found that the limit is:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{nx}{2 + n + x} = \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{x}{\frac{2}{n} + \frac{n}{n} + \frac{x}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{0+1+0} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} x = x.$$

The book confirms that,

but it says that it converges uniformly to $x$.

Why? the limit is dependent with $x$, so how does the convergence is uniformly?

Doesn't the definition says the a sequence of function converge uniformly to $f(x)$ if it dependent only on $\varepsilon > 0$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to prove that it is uniformly continuous (Hint: Look at the derivatives), and use Arzela-Ascoli.

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding of the definition of uniform convergence. The limit function $f$ can depend on $x$. What depends only on $\epsilon$ is the integer $n_\epsilon$ such that if $n\ge n_\epsilon$ then $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le\epsilon$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n$ are differentiable . Then use the fact that $f_n(x)\to x$ uniformly iff $\|f_n(x)-x\|_{\infty}\to 0$.You can find the maximum of $f_n(x)-x$ in terms of $n$ and show that the maximum goes to $0$ for $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Julián explains it very well in the comments, but I'll expand the discussion a bit. A sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ such that $f_{n}: E\subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for all $n$ converges uniformly to $f$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N(\epsilon)$, $|f_{n}(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in E$. **It is not** $f$ which is dependent on $\epsilon$; rather, it is $N$. In order for you to see that a particular sequence of functions is uniformly convergent, you would need to do more work than to simply take $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f_{n}(x)$ (unless there's some trick that I don't know about).

Let's prove that $\left\{\dfrac{nx}{2+n+x}\right\}^{\infty}_{1}$ converges uniformly to $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

**Proof**. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Choose $N:= \lceil 3\epsilon \rceil$. Then for all $n \geq N$,

$\begin{align}\left|\dfrac{nx}{2+n+x}-x\right| &= \left|\dfrac{nx-x(2+n+x)}{2+n+x}\right| \\
&= \left|\dfrac{-2x-x^{2}}{2+n+x}\right| \\
&= \left|\dfrac{2x+x^{2}}{2+n+x}\right| \\
&\leq \left|\dfrac{2x+x^{2}}{2+n}\right| \text{ since } x \in [0, 1] \\
&\leq \left|\dfrac{3}{2+n}\right| \text{ since } x \in [0, 1] \\
&< \left|\dfrac{3}{n}\right| \\
&= \dfrac{3}{n} \\
&< \dfrac{3}{\left(\dfrac{1}{3\epsilon}\right)} = \epsilon\end{align}$

for all $x \in [0, 1]$. Hence $\{f_{n}\} \to f$ uniformly for all $x \in [0, 1]$. (I might've messed up somewhere, since I did this rather quickly.) The point is the $N$ that we chose doesn't depend on $x$. (If it did, we would have pointwise convergence.)